# Can't choose Windows 10 after installing on laptop with Ubuntu already installed

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, windows-10

I installed Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on the same SSD of my laptop. Directly Ubuntu [GRUB] is coming. laptop is in boot legacy mode. Ran command sudo update-grub. grub2.0.2 has options 1.Ubuntu 2.Advanced options for Ubuntu 3.System set-up   Grub-image link- https://i.stack.imgur.com/juqql.jpg

Comment: GRUB _should_ appear, and it should give you the choice of Ubuntu or Windows. Please recheck the GRUB menu. If it does not show Microsoft Windows as the last item, please take a picture with a cellphone camera, go to http://imgur.com or some other image hosting site, post the picture there, then come back here, click [edit], and add the link to the picture in your question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Giving us a link to the Grub manual isn't helpful at all. Are you sure you installed both OS in legacy mode? If both OS are installed in legacy mode, Windows installation should have overwritten MBR with Grub. That's obviously not the case.

Comment: Have you run sudo update-grub in Ubuntu since you installed Windows?  That would be necessary to add the new Windows install  to the grub menu.

Comment: Grub legacy can't see UEFI partition, so if windows was installed using EFI you have to convert your grub to a grub EFI

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair